# Using cannonical constructor of local record (preview-feature) in Eclipse causes verify error

Tags: java, eclipse, java-record, java-15, preview-feature

I am Trying to use records preview-feature with cannonical constructors in Eclipse .

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        record Range() {
            Range {
            }
        }
        new Range();
    }
}
```

However, at run time a verify error is caused.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must
> call super() or this() before return Exception Details:   Location:
> Example$1Range.(II)V @36: return   Reason:
> Error exists in the bytecode   Bytecode:
> 0000000: 1b1c a400 22bb 000b 5912 0d05 bd00 0f59
> 0000010: 031b b800 1153 5904 1cb8 0011 53b8 0017
> 0000020: b700 1dbf b1                              Stackmap Table:
> same_frame(@36)
>
> at Example.main(Example.java:10)

This happens both in eclipse 2020-06 with JDK 14 and eclipse 2020-19 with JDK 15.0.1 and eclipse 15 support.

There is no problem running it from the command line with bin\java and no error is thrown then.

Is this working for anyone else on their eclipse?
Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. In this case, your record declaration is in an invalid location.

Comment: local records are valid. See https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384

Comment: It only fails when it is an inner class like this. As a separate class it is ok. Probably an issue with the Eclipse JDT compiler, report it on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)

Comment: Interesting; I hadn't seen the latest JEP, just 359.

Comment: Seems like an Eclipse bug.  Local records are allowed, and supported by `javac` in both 14 and 15 (in `--enable-preview` mode)

Comment: I reported the issue on bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=568922

Comment: @BrianGoetz I thought that the JEP359 (JDK14 preview) didn't include local records, and that it was only introduced in JEP384 (JDK15 preview).

Comment: The bugzilla status now shows this bug as verified fixed for SDK 4.18, scheduled for release with Eclipse 2020-12, but I have not tested it.